# Limit number of results for CalDav REPORT calendar-query

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, webdav, caldav

I'm trying to limit the number of results returned by calendar-query.

For example I need to find only 10 first events.
Can't find it in the description:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8.1
I can see that calendar service from google supports it:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

-maxResults

Is there anything like this for caldav REPORT ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`calendar-query`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8) `REPORT` is documented in [RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8). As far as I can see it doesn't provide the client a way to limit the number of results. (Note that a server *can* apply a limit and return a `number-of-matches-within-limits` precondition failure if it is hit by the query)

Having said that, the way it is usually done in clients is that they only fetch the URL and the `ETag` of the matching events/todos as part of a `calendar-query` `REPORT`. Only then they retrieve the actual event payloads in batches using a [`calendar-multiget`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.9) `REPORT` (that is, they can apply arbitrary limits in here).

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good point about combining calendar-query and calendar-multiget. I'm going to use exact this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the Google docs with regard to [CalDAV API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) and found no mention of a similar method like Calendar.list for that. Try to file a feature request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

Comment: Well, CalDAV is an IETF standard and in the case of CalDAV usually produced by the [CalConnect Consortium](https://www.calconnect.org). Though Google could add a proprietary custom property for this, this likely won't fly, as it would be, well, non-standard. If you think it is worth the effort, the proper way would be to submit an RFC extension draft for CalDAV, e.g. similar to [RFC7053](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7953).